# What is difference between windows 8 metro style app and windows 8 store app?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

In windows 8 consumer preview ,i used visual studio 2011 ,it has windows metro style app option.. and in windows 8 Pro i am using vs 2012 it has windows store app option ,there is no windows 8 metro option available in vs2012..is windows metro and store apps one and the same?

Comment: None , they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed the same this. "Windows Store apps" is the final name. The name change is speculated to be for legal reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Store Apps used to be called Metro Style apps, but then Microsoft ran into some issues with one of its partners in Europe and had to come up with a new name.  Now they are called Windows Store Apps.